# Multiplying into an infinite sum

Tags: summation, series-expansion

Suppose I define `y = Sum[Subscript[a, k] x^k, {k, 0, Infinity}]` which is a power series representation for `y`. Now if I multiply `y` by `bx^n+cx^m` I want the resulting answer to be sum of two power series: `Sum[b Subscript[a, k] x^(k+n), {k, 0, Infinity}] + Sum[c Subscript[a, k] x^(k+m), {k, 0, Infinity}]`. However simply writing `(bx^n+cx^m)y` does not achieve this. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can work with ReplaceAll rules

```
y = Sum[a[k] x^k, {k, 0, Infinity}]

y1 = y /. y[[1]] -> (y[[1]]*(b x^n + c x^m) // Expand)
```

[image]

```
y2 = y1 /. Sum[r_ + s_, t_] :> Sum@Sequence[r, t] + Sum@Sequence[s, t]
```

[image]